# Iterate a list of 3 elements multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a Hangman game for a class proyect, and I would like to iterate a list which represents the turns of a determinate number of players.

```
dic_players = {0: 'Juan',1: 'Pepe',2: 'Luis'}
player_turns = [2,1,0]
```

How would you iterate "player_turns" multiple times? If they don't get removed from the game (The value in the original dictionary is a list with multiple numbers, some represent number of fails and stuff), the turns would be 'Luis', 'Pepe', 'Juan', 'Luis', 'Pepe', 'Juan' and so

Answer (score 0):

You need a double for loop. You need to iterate over the number of rounds in the game, and for each round you need to iterate over the all the players.

`for round in range(3):
    print('round %d' % round)
    for playerId in player_turns:
        print('%s\'s turn' % dic_players[playerId])
        # do stuff`

Comment: Please indent your code to make it readable